# Activex Update - IE

Tags: c#, activex, cab

I've developed a C# activex control, build a relative MSI, putting all of them in a CAB file and finally I've deployed it through IE.
All works fine.

Now, I need to update the activex control, but it seems impossible to accomplish.
After reading any articles about that, here what I tried to do:

1. Changed file version and assembly versionof my .net dll
2. Changed version number of my installer.msi
3. Changed file version of Inf file used by CABARC
4. Changed OBJECT tag in the HTML page to #version=x,x,x,x

Nonetheless, activex newest version never being downloaded, nor installed.

Any idea will be appreciated..
Thank you in advance

Comment: If I remove the current version manually, then the newest version is being installed correctly, but OBVIOUSLY it isn't the behavior I'm looking for. When I put my new bac veersion serer side, I want an automatic activex updating.

Comment: Sure..My installer is configured in order to allow updating.

Comment: Yes. It is configured to remove previous version, then install newest version.

Comment: Your saying the installer does not actually do this because your having the described problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution:

in order to allow .NET activex auto update, we need to add following key manually:

for x64 client machine:

Key: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID{GUID}\InstalledVersion

with name: (Default)

of type: REG_SZ

with value: 1,5,3,2 (it will be your assembly file version, exactly as you have defined in HTML tag OBJECT for cab version.

Please use decimals with **comma** separator.

For x86 target machine I think it's the same, except for wow6432Node key.

Note that is possibile accomplish by MSI project without write any code..